# Custom DLL showing in Object Browser but Excel is showing "User-defined type not defined"

Tags: excel, vb.net, dll, dllimport

I have a .DLL that I've written in VB.Net to be used in Excel. For context the .DLL is supposed to go and retrieve a dataset from an SQL server, convert it to a ADODB.RecordSet that Excel can use.

I've registered from COM interop use and made the assembly COM-Visible by following the instructions here: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2013/10/make-a-c-dll-and-use-it-from-excel-vba-code/

The dll appears in Tools -> References in excel VBA editor.

EDIT
@Rory spotted the mistake on the second line with the incorrect 'set' code. I have corrected this but no improvement.

[image]

When I go to look in the Object Browser it also appears there.

[image]

However when I go to run the sub routine it fails on the first line with the error message "User-defined type not defined".

I've seen other questions which recommend trying late binding with `Set objMyConn = CreateObject("bbsSQLForExcel.SQLCOMS")` but this produces an error where excel cannot create the Active X component.

If posting the code for the DLL would help then I can do that as well. (Its not huge)

EDIT Comment have pointed the error could be to do with my VB.net code so I'm going to post it up here and add the vb.net tag.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Namespace bbsSQLForExcel
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Class SQLCOMS

    Function SQLDate(ByVal dtmDate As DateTime, Optional ByVal blTime As Boolean = False) As String
        'From @BBS, TimeLog, BulkMailer, Contacts, BBSProjects, SchemeDocs, Billings, FileLoader.
        Dim strDate As String
        strDate = Month(dtmDate) & "/" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Day(dtmDate) & "/" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Year(dtmDate)
        If blTime Then
            strDate &= " " & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Hour(dtmDate) & ":" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Minute(dtmDate) & ":00"
        End If
        SQLDate = "CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & strDate & "', 102)"

    End Function

    Function RunSQL(ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal strDatabase As String, Optional ByVal strTeam As String = "", Optional ByVal blAlwaysDS As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal blTimeLogComments As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal blSomerfield As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal blUsePayrollLive As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal intTimeOutOverride As Integer = 15) As ADODB.Recordset

        'Fom FileLoader, BBS Contacts, BulkMailer, Time Log, SchemeDocs, Bookings, Accounts, @BBS, Billings, Projects, TimeCost

        Dim strConn As String
        Dim sqlConnection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        Dim sqlCommand As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim dataAdapter As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet

        Select Case strDatabase

            Case "Employees", "Users"
                strConn = "data source=192.168.0.222;initial catalog=BBSEmployees;persist security info=False;user id=user;workstation id=DELL_LT;packet size=4096;password=pwd"
            Case "P3"
                strConn = "data source=192.168.0.222;initial catalog=p3;persist security info=False;user id=user;workstation id=DELL_LT;packet size=4096;password=pwd"
                If Not (blUsePayrollLive) Then
                    strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "PayrollSQL", "PayrollSQLTest", , , CompareMethod.Text)
                End If
        End Select

        sqlConnection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConn)
        strSQL = "Set Arithabort ON; " + strSQL

        sqlCommand = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlConnection)
        sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = intTimeOutOverride
        dataAdapter = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand)
        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet()

        Try
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return ConvertToRecordset(dataSet.Tables(0))
        Exit Function

    End Function

    Public Shared Function ConvertToRecordset(ByVal inTable As DataTable) As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim result As ADODB.Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset()
        result.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
        Dim resultFields As ADODB.Fields = result.Fields
        Dim inColumns As System.Data.DataColumnCollection = inTable.Columns

        For Each inColumn As DataColumn In inColumns
            resultFields.Append(inColumn.ColumnName, TranslateType(inColumn.DataType), inColumn.MaxLength, If(inColumn.AllowDBNull, ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldIsNullable, ADODB.FieldAttributeEnum.adFldUnspecified), Nothing)
        Next

        result.Open(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, 0)

        For Each dr As DataRow In inTable.Rows
            result.AddNew(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)

            For columnIndex As Integer = 0 To inColumns.Count - 1
                resultFields(columnIndex).Value = dr(columnIndex)
            Next
        Next

        Return result
    End Function

    Private Shared Function TranslateType(ByVal columnType As Type) As ADODB.DataTypeEnum
        Select Case columnType.UnderlyingSystemType.ToString()
            Case "System.Boolean"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBoolean
            Case "System.Byte"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedTinyInt
            Case "System.Char"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adChar
            Case "System.DateTime"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDate
            Case "System.Decimal"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adCurrency
            Case "System.Double"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adDouble
            Case "System.Int16"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSmallInt
            Case "System.Int32"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger
            Case "System.Int64"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adBigInt
            Case "System.SByte"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adTinyInt
            Case "System.Single"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adSingle
            Case "System.UInt16"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedSmallInt
            Case "System.UInt32"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedInt
            Case "System.UInt64"
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adUnsignedBigInt
            Case Else
                Return ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar
        End Select
    End Function
End Class
```

End Namespace

Comment: Your second line appears to be wrong anyway - shouldn't it be: `Set SQLFuns = New bbsSQLForExcel.SQLCOMS`?

Comment: Hi @Rory I've updated this is I still get the same issue. Good spot none the less.

Comment: When you typed the `As ` on the `Dim` line, did Intellisense show `bbsSQLForExcel` as an available namespace?

Comment: For bbsSQLForExcel did appear, however when I put in the "." afterwards no intellisense showed afterwards.

Comment: C# is not really my thing, but did you definitely make the *class* COMVisible as well as the namespace?

Comment: Like Rory, C# is not my field.   But it sounds like the issue is in the dll code. Maybe you should ask a Q about _that_ code

Comment: The code I've written is in VB.Net if that's more along your street?